# How do i link to a users gallery in PHP

Tags: php, hyperlink

I have asked this before, but i did not make myself clear so im going to articulate better.

I am making a project for fun and to train my php skills. On my site i have users who can register and check out each others profile. Thats where my problem start.

To list all my users, and make links to their specific private presentations works fine. But my navigation on the visited persons private presentation does not work.

For example lets say i visit user with an id of 48 then the URL shows

localhost/c9/otheruser.php?id=48

and i can look at the presentation and picture on that users page.

But say for example that i press the link for id=48,s gallery the URL will show

localhost/c9/othergallery.php?id=%2745%27

Which as you all can se is not right. it should show

localhost/c9/othergallery.php?id=48.

I know that i somehow must get the navigation on the visited user to understand
which id it belongs to, in order for it to work. And i have looked for help evrywhere for this problem.

This is my code for showing the user that i am currently visiting.
Im only pasting the code that is relevant, this code works in order to show the presentation.

```
<?php 

    $userId = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE id = :id";

     $stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);

     $stmt->execute(['id' => $userId]);

     ?>
<?php

if ( $stmt->rowCount() > 0 ) {

    while ( $row = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC ) ) {
        ?>
```

This is the link i am using that does not work as i want it

```
<?php $userId = $row['id'] ;?>
    <td>
       <a href="othergallery.php?id='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'">
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture" aria-hidden="true">Gallery</i>
    </a>
  </td>
```

I have also tried $userId only.

```
<td>
       <a href="othergallery.php?id='<?php echo $userId; ?>'">
       <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture" aria-hidden="true">Gallery</i>
    </a>
  </td>
```

This site is not live, just a test so im not asking for any security related answears.

Best of regards / Robert

Comment: You shouldn't have the quotes in the href. `<a href="othergallery.php?id=<?= $row['id']; ?>">`

Comment: I'd suggest changing from otherprofile/othergallery to just profile/gallery. Just check if there is a `$_GET['id']`, if it is, load the profile/gallery for that user, if not, load the gallery for the logged in user ^^

Comment: @JimL Jesus Christ i think u fixed it with just the quotes. Why did  it not work with the quotes?

Comment: It did work, the quotes just showed up in the url encoded, as urls aren't really fond of special characters.

Comment: @JimL Im also gonna test ur $_GET['id'] solution and thank you again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

%27 is the URL encoded ' character.

Try `<a href="othergallery.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'">`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
<a href="othergallery.php?id='<?php echo $row['id']; ?>'">
```

Use:

```
<a href="othergallery.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
```

Remove the quotes around the PHP part.

Comment: As @neil pointed out `%27` is the urlencoded equivalent of `'`. The same goes for an image url with a space but a space is `%20`. You can see it here http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php under "User Contributed Notes" the first example

Comment: Ah thanks for that lesson and im reading the manual as we speak. And now i can finaly sleep xD